# Cloud Firestore - still get "any user can write to your entire database" error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've added rules to my Cloud Firestore database but still receive these issue messages:

- any user can read your entire database
- any user can write to your entire database

See the rules below.

[image]

Indeed, any user can read and write into "users" collection, otherwise I won't be able to log in/register a user. How to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is your rule that matches `/{document=**}`, since it matches every single document in your database.  This is too broad.  Narrow your rules down to individual collections as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your current rules is that it allows any user to read/write any other user's user document. You need to restrict it a bit more to look at the userId of the documents. Something like this

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Ensure the user is authenticated
    function userIsAuthenticated() {
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null
    }

    // Ensure the user owns the existing resource
    function userOwnsResource() {
        return userIsAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId
    }

    // Ensure the user owns the new resource
    function userOwnsNewResource() {
      return userIsAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId 
    }

    match /users/{userId=**} {
      allow read, update, delete: if userOwnsResource();
      allow create: if userOwnsNewResource();
    }
  }
}
```

`userOwnsResource` checks that the user can access an existing resource. `userOwnsNewResource` checks that they can create a new document for their userId. You can obviously reuse these functions in other rules which is handy.

Comment: Thanks Chris!
That's what I need!